# How can I split incoming mail into several mails in Mail.app?

Tags: macos, email, apple-mail, email-filter

I am receiving some bundled emails whose text bodies are delimited by dashes. I would prefer to have each body content in a separate mail, replacing the subject with maybe the first string of the body to identify it better.

In the good old days I would use fetchmail+procmail+formail+regular expressions to do this in the time the MTA is passing the mail to the local MUA.

Is there a way to accomplish the same thing in Mail.app using its filtering rules while talking to an IMAP server? I've checked /Library/Scripts/Mail Scripts but didn't find anything close other than the script that creates new mail, but that requires user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the "[Burst digest messages](http://homepage.mac.com/aamann/Misc_Scripts.html)" applescript. From its description:

> This AppleScript for Mail will take
>   one or more selected digest messages
>   (messages formatted as either
>   multipart/digest (MIME digest)
>   according to RFC2046 or simple digest
>   as defined by RFC1153) and extract the
>   individual messages from the digest
>   message - this is especially useful if
>   you are subscribed to a mailing list
>   in digest format but want to reply to
>   a single message in the digest rather
>   than the digest message itself.

(found this via HawkWings.net [list of Mail plug-ins](http://www.hawkwings.net/plugins.htm))

Answer (score 0):

I may damage my reputation for this but if you run Windows on your Mac, perhaps you could import your mail into Outlook Express 6, close this and run express-archiver (download from expressarchiver.com) which is very powerful and can save each of your emails as a plain text file with all of the header information, encoded attachments (or them placed in a folder if you want). It also has powerful renaming options to give each file.

Not a Mac solution but may do what you want.